# inkscape: multiple page pdf to multiple png

Tags: pdf, inkscape

when I convert pdf to image in linux command line, it seems inkscape gets the best result (better quality than gs with same dpi). Unfortunately, it only converts the first page to png. How to convert every pdf page to different png file? Do I have to extract one PDF page and store to a new pdf file , then do inkscape concert, and so on?

Comment: Nothing to do with PostScript as far as I can see.

Comment: Will be possible in 1.0 via command line - import one page, export, new document, repeat. See https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#Command_Line

Answer (score 1):

This isn't solely using Inkscape, but you could use e.g. pdftk to split up the pdf-file into separate pages and convert every page into a png with Inkscape. For example, like this:

```
pdftk file.pdf burst;
l=$(ls pg_*.pdf)
for i in $l; do inkscape "$i" -z --export-dpi=300 --export-area-page --export-png="$i.png"; done
```

**Note** that `pdftk burst` creates pdf-files called pg_0001.pdf, etc., so if you have any files named like that, they'll be overwritten. You can remove them afterwards easily using

```
rm pg_*.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Lu Kas' answer threw warnings for me without doing the conversion. Probably because I'm running Inkscape 1.1

However, i got it running by replacing some deprecated commands:

```
inkscape pdfFile.pdf --export-dpi=300 --export-area-page --export-filename=imageFile.png;
```

Answer (score 0):

For batch processing rather than slowly looping through file by file inkscape has a shell mode for command file scripting. See https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line#Shell_mode

However like all other @file.txt scripts you need to write a custom text file. and for Windows users run against higher ranking inkscape.com not .exe

Since version 1.0 (currently 1.2) a multipage pdf of contents can be addressed for multiple outputs. for some other examples see https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html#EXAMPLES

Commands get replaced over time so currently to export png use `--export-type="xxx" to batch export a list of input files to type xxx.` Thus in this case `--export-type="png"`

Also for pdf related inputs and support see https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line#New_options

For windows users there is a handy batchfile converter here https://gist.github.com/JohannesDeml/779b29128cdd7f216ab5000466404f11